How to make the value of 'isPlayerTurn' change via firebase function?
Using  Vue, firebase functions and realtime database. The 'isPlayerTurn.value' returns false only, it never changes.  I have tried changing the values/ parameters many times, have tried using AI to suggest problems, it mostly says that the code works.  It does allow the creation of matchmaking and the turn does shift between users.   However the button color is never changed as the 'isPlayerTurn.value' doesn't change.
<script setup>
import { ref, watchEffect, computed } from 'vue';
import { httpsCallable } from 'firebase/functions';
import { functions, realTime, auth } from '@/firebase';
import { ref as dbRef, onValue, off } from 'firebase/database';

import { onAuthStateChanged } from 'firebase/auth';

const gameId = ref('');
const playerId = ref('');
const gameTurnRef = ref('');
const isPlayerTurn = ref('');

onAuthStateChanged(auth, (user) => {
  if (user) {
    playerId.value = user.uid;
    console.log('player id:', playerId.value)
  } else {
    // Handle the case when the user is not authenticated
  }
});

const updateGameTurnRef = () => {
  if (gameId.value) {
    gameTurnRef.value = dbRef(realTime, `games/${gameId.value}/turn`);
  }
};

watchEffect(() => {
  console.log('gameId:', gameId.value);
  updateGameTurnRef();
});

watchEffect(() => {
  if (!gameTurnRef.value) return;

  const gameTurnRefListener = onValue(gameTurnRef.value, (snapshot) => {
    const turn = snapshot.val();
    console.log('turn:', turn);
    if (turn !== null) {
      isPlayerTurn.value = turn; // === playerId.value;
    } else {
      console.error('Invalid turn data:', turn);
    }
  }, (error) => {
    console.error('Error fetching turn data:', error);
  });

  return () => {
    off(gameTurnRefListener);
  };
});

const endTurn = async () => {
  try {
    const makeMove = httpsCallable(functions, "makeMove");
    const response = await makeMove(playerId.value);

    if (response.data && response.data.turn !== undefined) {
      isPlayerTurn.value = response.data.turn === playerId.value;
      console.log('is player turn:', isPlayerTurn.value);
      console.log('is response turn:', response.data.turn);
      console.log('is player :', response.data);
    }
  } catch (error) {
    console.error('Error making move:', error);
  }
};

const buttonBackgroundColor = computed(() => {
  return isPlayerTurn.value ? 'red' : 'blue';
});
</script>

<template>
  <button @click="endTurn" :style="{ backgroundColor: buttonBackgroundColor}">End Turn</button>
</template>

<style scoped>
button {
  width: 100px;
}
</style>

Firebase Function
exports.makeMove = functions.https.onCall((data, context) => {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    try {
      assertAuth(context);

      const playerId = context.auth.uid;
      const move = data; // Expecting a string directly

      assertValidMove(move); // Validate the move

      // Check player is in a game
      RTDB.ref("matchmaking/" + playerId + "/gameId")
          .once("value")
          .then((gameIdSnapshot) => {
            const gameId = gameIdSnapshot.val();
            if (!gameId) {
              throw new functions.https
                  .HttpsError("failed-precondition", "Player is not in a game");
            }

            const gameRef = RTDB.ref("games/" + gameId);
            const playersRef = gameRef.child("gameInfo/playersInfo");
            const movesRef = gameRef.child(playerId + "/moves");
            const turnRef = gameRef.child("turn");

            // Check if it's the player's turn
            gameRef.once("value")
                .then((gameSnapshot) => {
                  const isPlayerTurn = gameSnapshot
                      .child("turn").val() === playerId;
                  if (!isPlayerTurn) {
                    throw new functions.https
                        .HttpsError("failed-precondition"
                            , "It's not your turn");
                  }

                  // Enact the player move
                  return movesRef.push().set(move)
                      .then(() => {
                        return playersRef.once("value")
                            .then((snapshot) => {
                              const players = snapshot.val();
                              const playerIds = Object.keys(players);
                              const nextTurnPlayer =
                              playerIds
                                  .find((id) => id !== playerId) ||
                                  playerIds[0];

                              // Update turn
                              return turnRef.set(nextTurnPlayer)
                                  .then(() => {
                                    // Resolve with the updated turn status
                                    resolve({turn: nextTurnPlayer ===
                                      playerId ? true : false});
                                  })
                                  .catch((error) => {
                                    reject(error);
                                  });
                            })
                            .catch((error) => {
                              reject(error);
                            });
                      })
                      .catch((error) => {
                        reject(error);
                      });
                })
                .catch((error) => {
                  reject(error);
                });
          })
          .catch((error) => {
            reject(error);
          });
    } catch (error) {
      console.error("ERROR:", error);
      reject(new functions.https.HttpsError("internal", error.message));
    }
  });
});

function assertValidMove(move) {
  // Assuming `move` is a string representing the move
  if (typeof move !== "string" || move.trim() === "") {
    throw new functions.https.HttpsError(
        "invalid-argument",
        "Move is not a valid string",
    );
  }
}


realtime structure

realtime structure ctd
I have tried switching variable properties multiple times.  Thinking about the logical structure.
But I still cannot work out why it is not working.
Expecting.  When one player clicks on the button the button should change to red and for the other player it should then turn to blue and vice-versa.  Initially, I expect both players to have the button to be set to blue.  Ideally, they should both be neutral until the sequence starts... the login stages set the initial player turn.   But that is something that I am not concerned with  (if anyone could solve that issue as well though then that would be amazing)

Please see [ask], then revise your title to ask a clear, specific question and not just describe your project.
